# Swift : Useless default value for Optional?

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm creating a function like this :

```
func foo(bar: UInt? = 0) {
  let doSomething = someOtherFunc(bar!)
}
```

If i'm passing to `foo()` a `nil` value, i'm expecting the default value of 0 to be used instead while unwrapping it, but rather than that i'm getting the usual error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Where am I wrong here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default value `= 0` is only used if you *don't provide* an argument 
for the optional parameter:

```
func foo(bar: UInt? = 0) {
    println(bar)
}

foo(bar: nil) // nil
foo(bar: 1)   // Optional(1)
foo()         // Optional(0), default value used
```

If your intention is to replace a passed `nil` value by `0`
then you can use the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
func foo(bar: UInt?) {
    println(bar ?? 0)
}

foo(nil) // 0
foo(1)   // 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Default values are not for when `nil` is passed in.  Default values apply when the caller does not supply a value – that is, if you called your function as `foo()`.

If you want a default value to be applied when the user passes in `nil`, you should use the nil-coalescing operator, `??`:

```
func foo(bar: UInt?) {
  // bar replaced with 0 when it is nil, else it's unwrapped
  let doSomething = someOtherFunc(bar ?? 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `nil` to the function, but inside the function you force unwrap the value with `!`, so it crashes.

You should use `if let x = y {` (or any other relevant technique) to prevent this:

```
func foo(bar: UInt? = 0) {
    if let input = bar {
        someOtherFunc(input)
    }
}

func someOtherFunc(bar: UInt) {
    println(bar)
}

foo(bar: 42)    // Prints "42"
foo(bar: nil)  // Does nothing
```

Comment: Well, giving what you're saying, the default value is useless, so i still don't get it. If i'm using foo(bar: nil), it's supposed to use the 0 default value, not doing nothing.

Comment: Check @martin-r 's excellent answer for details. :) (I didn't provide an example about the default value, only about the unwrapping.)